# Open Weather API Working not working in Safari or Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fetch-api, openweathermap

I have used Open Weather map API in my Vanilla JS weather app. Everything works fine when viewing the site in Google Chrome.

The problem starts when the site is viewed from Firefox or Safari, the API does not fetch data and the site just displays default values. How can I make this work cross-browser?

Here's the link to the website:
https://getweathernow.netlify.app

I have attached my app.js code below:

```
window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
    let longitude;
    let latitude;
    let tempertarueDescription = document.querySelector(".temperature-description");
    let tempertarueHumidity = document.querySelector(".temperature-humidity");
    let temperatureDegree = document.querySelector(".temperature-degree");
    let locationTimezone = document.querySelector(".location-timezone");
    let temperatureSection = document.querySelector(".temperature-section");
    const temperatureSpan = document.querySelector(".temperature-section span");



    if(navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
            longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            latitude = position.coords.latitude;

            const proxy = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
            const api_key = 'a1e11e328b6e8c7efa6d65034aa533dc';
            const api = `${proxy}api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=${api_key}`;


            fetch(api)

            .then(response => {
                return response.json();
            })

            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                const kelvin = data.main.temp;
                const celsius = Math.round(kelvin - 273.15);
                temperatureDegree.textContent = celsius;

                //Celius to Fahrenheit Conversion
                let fahrenheit = Math.round(((celsius * 1.8)+ 32));

                function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
                    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
                }

                const description = data.weather[0].description;
                tempertarueDescription.textContent = capitalizeFirstLetter(description);

                const locale = data.name;
                locationTimezone.textContent = locale;

                //Select C/F on click 
                temperatureSection.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    if (temperatureSpan.textContent === "℃") {
                        temperatureSpan.textContent = "℉";
                        temperatureDegree.textContent = fahrenheit;
                    }
                    else {
                        temperatureSpan.textContent = "℃";
                        temperatureDegree.textContent = celsius;
                    }
                })
                
                var iconcode = data.weather[0].icon;
                var iconurl = "https://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + iconcode + ".png";
                $('#wicon').attr('src', iconurl);
                
            })
        })
    }
    else 
    {
        h1.textContent = "Error: Request Denied." <br> "User Location Could Not Be Determined.";
    }
});
```

Here's the Output on Google Chrome:

[image]

Here's the Output on other browsers (These are just the default placeholders in index.html):

[image]

Comment: Could you tell us what gets returned by the API on Safari & Firefox?

Comment: Hi @JonathanS. I have attached the screenshots of outputs on both browsers. Please have a look.